# convert numpy array of size n into a scalar with sub-item index numbers as scalar values

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, scalar

I want to convert a numpy array

```
a =    array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

into a scalar with sub-item index numbers as scalar values

**desired output**

```
a1 = array([[1],[1],[3],[3],[6],[4]])
```

I tried this method:

```
a1 = []
for item in a:
    a1.append(np.where(item==1))
```

and I get this output:

```
a1 = [(array([0]),),
 (array([0]),),
 (array([2]),),
 (array([2]),),
 (array([6]),),
 (array([4]),)]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question more carefully, I think this one-liner should
solve your issue in a more pythonic way:

```
np.where(a==1)[1].reshape((a.shape[0],1))
```

If you prefer starting indexing with `1` instead of `0` (as is evident in your desired output), then you just have to add a `1` to the line above, i.e.

```
np.where(a==1)[1].reshape((a.shape[0],1)) + 1
```

Note that there seems to be an error in your example output above for the last two elements.